# Function return boolean statement

Tags: javascript, function, variables, boolean, conditional-statements

Task Instructions

Your task in this activity is to create a function that checks if a person is old enough to vote by checking their age. This function is called isOldEnoughToVote(age) and has the following specifications:
It takes an argument called age representing the age of the person.
It checks if the age is greater than or equal to 18.
If returns true or false based on that comparison.

*This is what I've written so far but It says result is not defined and I'm wondering why.*

```
let response;
var age = 18
// Add your code here
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
 if (age >= 18){
   result; 'true'
 }else{
   result; 'false'
 }
```

Comment: It is `return` - not result

Comment: Also remove the semi-colon, and use booleans not strings.

Comment: change (result; 'false') to (return false;) the same with the "return true;".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example is using `result; 'true'` (for example) to indicate a `true` result.  This doesn't do anything - in fact it's not correct at all.

Instead it should use `return true`:

let response;

```js
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  if (age >= 18) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(10));
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18));
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(50));
```

However, this could be simplified even further by just returning the result of `age >= 18`:

```js
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  return age >= 18;
}

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(10));
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18));
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(50));
```

Comment: Thank you! The return value makes a lot more sense thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of typos: `;` should be `=` and you should actually return a Boolean, not a String value:

```js
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  return age >= 18;
} 

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(17)); // false
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18)); // true
```

Or, if you like more [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```js
const isOldEnoughToVote = (age) => age >= 18;

// The first => is an arrow function's "Fat Arrow"
// The second >= is an greater-or-equal operator

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(17)); // false
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18)); // true
```

Regarding your code, there's also that `response` variable but you never assigned anything to it, instead you're trying to do something with that `result; 'true'`.

***If*** you really need to **return two strings** `"true"` and `"false"` you can do it like:

```js
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  if (age < 18) {
    return "false";
  } else {
    return "true";
  }
} 

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(17)); // "false"
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18)); // "true"
```

Or by using an Arrow Function and the [Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `?:`

```js
const isOldEnoughToVote = (age) => age < 18 ? "false" : "true";

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(17)); // "false"
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18)); // "true"
```

Or you could convert the Boolean to string using .toString():

```js
const isOldEnoughToVote = (age) => (age >= 18).toString();

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(17)); // "false"
console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18)); // "true"
```

But I still think your task should be to return a Boolean, not a String :)

Comment: It feels funny to see a the ternary truthy evaluation return the string false  but in this example it also shows using another comparison operator for age and 18 and demonstrates the conditional well.

Answer (score 1):

That error means the variable `result` within the function, is not defined.

You don't need to do that at all though, return the boolean directly.

```
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  if (age >= 18) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

In the above, you don't need the `else` since it would be the only other result. So you could do:

```
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  if (age >= 18) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Or you can more simply return the result of the comparison.

```
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
  return age >= 18;
}
```

Comment: Your second demo is incorrect. He needs to add ```else``` otherwise  it will always return false

Comment: No, the return causes function to exit

Answer (score 0):

```js
let response;
var age = 18
// Add your code here
function isOldEnoughToVote(age) {
 if (age >= 18){
   return true;
 } else {
   return false;
 } 
}

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(18));

console.log(isOldEnoughToVote(8));
```